# Unblock All Ports in CSF?

Tags: linux, centos, csf

I have CSF installed on a cPanel server and know that I believe that I can unblock ports specifically for outgoing connections in the `/etc/csf/csf.conf` file.

It looks like this line can just be edited:

```
# Allow outgoing TCP ports
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,113,443,587,873"
```

However, I need to unblock all ports for outgoing connections.  Does anyone know if this is possible to do is CSF?  It seems like it would be a bit odd for them to force you to list every one manually...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TCP_OUT = "1:65535"

Unless they changed it, that is how it is done.

Comment: Syntax still works 6 years later!

Comment: confirmed . still works. thanks